# using list lookup Fields in SharePoint 2010 programmatically

Tags: web-part, list, visual-studio, lookup-column

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set ListItem Lookup Field value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/how-to-set-listitem-lookup-field-value)

I have a SharePoint list with a lookup field and I want to add values to this list through the SharePoint Object Model.

but I always get a value out of range for the lookup field when I submit the changes.

any clues or guides on storing lookup fields in code?

Comment: This is nearly identical to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/how-to-set-listitem-lookup-field-value so merging these two questions. Thanks.