# How to set a lookup field by c# code

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation

I have a list in SharePoint and it contains a lookup field. Now I want to insert an item to this list, but don't know how to work with the lookup field. I tried the following code but no item is added.

```
SPFieldLookupValue gov = new SPFieldLookupValue(gv.SelectedValue);
items["gov_name"] = gov.LookupValue;
items.Update();
```

Comment: I thought my question is very easy but it's important for me :(

Comment: I have edited your question (changed formatting). Please, approve this edit. It will help others in future.

Comment: Check this [Get and Set a SharePoint Lookup Field Values Using SSOM C#](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40271.get-and-set-a-sharepoint-lookup-field-values-using-ssom-c.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, take a look at [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/how-to-set-listitem-lookup-field-value). So you can do something like this:

```
SPListItem lookedUpItem =  GetItemSomeHow();
newItem[lookupField] = new SPFieldLookupValue( lookedUpItem.ID, lookedUpItem.Title);
newItem.Update();
```

Hope it helps. If so, please, don't forget to press upvote and mark as answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for reply but What's getitemsomehow ??

Comment: this means that you need to obtain an SPListItem object you want to lookup to. For instance it could look like: SPListItem lookedUpItem=web.Lists["SomeList"].Items[1] for the item with ID=1 in the list "SomeList";