# I want fill dynamically the lookupFields with method Insert in class + C#

Tags: development

my code is

```
 public static void AddNew(string title,string AddedDate, string Discription, string AddedByLoginName)
    {
        using (SPSite sps1 = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb spw1 = sps1.OpenWeb())
            {

                SPList std = spw1.Lists["WorkFlowTaskHistory"];
                SPListItem NewRecord = std.AddItem();

                NewRecord["Task"] = new SPFieldLookupValue (title);
                NewRecord["AddedDate"] = AddedDate;
                NewRecord["Discription"] = Discription;
                NewRecord["AddedByLoginName"] = AddedByLoginName;
                NewRecord.Update();
            }

        }

    }
```

but no add new record

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass the ID of the look up item to the SPFieldLooupValue. Please take a look at [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/how-to-set-listitem-lookup-field-value).